# incorrect Locale when displaying a variable with a date

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a DatePicker and when I just added it to the code, days and months were automatically written in my language (Russian), but now for some reason it writes in English

I added locale ('ru') but it didn't help. Language changed only in the calendar when you select the date, when the output variable with the selected date, it is displayed in English, and you need in Russian

```
  Future<Null> selectDate(BuildContext context) async {
    final DateTime picked = await showDatePicker(
      context: context,
      initialDate: date,
      firstDate: dateNow,
      lastDate: sixtyDaysFromNow,initialDatePickerMode: DatePickerMode.day,
      locale: Locale('ru','RU'),
    );
     sendDateToChooseTime(BuildContext context) {
       print(picked);
      Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => ChooseTime(picked: DateFormat('EEEE dd MMMM').format(picked), phoneNumber:phoneNumber, service:service),
          ));
    }
    if (picked != null ) {
      Locale myLocale = Localizations.localeOf(context);
     // String picked = DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd – kk:mm').format(now);
      sendDateToChooseTime(context);
    }

  }
localizationsDelegates: [
          // ... app-specific localization delegate[s] here
          GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
          GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
        ],
        supportedLocales: [
          const Locale('en', 'US'),
          const Locale('ru'),
        ],
```

Comment: Have you changed your device/emulator locale?

Comment: from the beginning, once I made this class the language was Russian, then I changed the language in the phone and did not notice that in the application the language was also changed. And when I changed the language in the phone back to Russian, in the application English and remained